# Search Cell Value by Part, Replace Entire Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to search all cells on my named worksheet (AdjacencyData) to see if they contain the value "NOT FOUND IN MASTER CATEGORY LIST." My cells contain long strings, and hidden somewhere with in them could be the phrase. I want to search the entire cell to see if that phrase is anywhere within, and then if the cell contains that phrase anywhere within, replace the entire value with the cell with a new phrase "LOCATION UNSURE" Is there any way to do this? I have some guesses, but I am not very good with the find and replace option.

```
find = "NOT FOUND IN MASTER CAT LIST"
f = AdjacencyData.Cells.find(What:=find, lookat:=xlPart)
If f Is Nothing Then
    Else
```

Don't know what to do next, this partial code is my only idea!

Comment: Just need to use the Range.Replace method with wildcards: `AdjacencyData.Cells.Replace "*NOT FOUND IN MASTER CAT LIST*", "LOCATION UNSURE", xlWhole`

Answer (score 1):

You will want to invest in the `.Range.FindNext` function:

```
FindMe = "NOT FOUND IN MASTER CAT LIST"
With Sheets("AdjacencyData").Range("Defined Range") 
    Set f = .Find(What:=FindMe, lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not f Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = f.Address 
        Do 
            f.Value = "LOCATION UNSURE" 
            Set f = .FindNext(f) 
        Loop While Not f Is Nothing And f.Address <> firstAddress 
    End If 
End With
```

Comment: Range.FindNext isn't really necessary.  Can be done with a single `Range.Replace`

Comment: @tigeravatar True.  Suggest it as an answer and I'll upvote.  However, this method works as well.

Comment: What would it look like to do with a simple Range.Replace? Would that search the cell to see if it contains the phrase, but then change the entire cell value?